# Dynamically changeable QCheckBox list

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qgis

I'm currently developing plugin for QGIS with Python 2.7 and PyQt 4. My plugin should have checkable list of map layers (could be list of items, irrelevant) that would be regenerated each time user opens Settings tab. Although I managed to create checkable list of QCheckBoxes which regenerates each time I click Settings button, it's still far from good and functional one. As I figured out, my problem is mostly parent-child relationship and layout deletion.

```
    self.layers = qgis_api.get_layers()
    #ScrollArea setup
    if (api.selected_upload_layers == [] and
        api.project.layerTreeRoot().children() != []):
        self.tmp_layers = qgis_api.get_layers()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.settingsDock.groupBox)
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scroll)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setFixedHeight(111)
        self.scrollContent = QWidget(self.scroll)
        self.scrollLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.scrollContent)
        self.scrollContent.setLayout(self.scrollLayout)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.scrollContent)

    i = 0
    self.checkboxes = []
    for layer in self.layers:
        self.checkboxes.append(QCheckBox("{0}".format(layer.name())))
        self.checkboxes[i].stateChanged.connect(lambda checked, i = i : self.cBoxChecked(self.checkboxes[i])) #inverts logic if run every time
        # check logic
        if i < len(self.layers)-1:
            i += 1
    # Create checkboxes first time
    if not api.upload:  #api.upload becomes true when clicked save in settings
        for i in range(0, len(self.layers)):
            try:
                self.scrollLayout.addWidget(self.checkboxes[i])
                self.checkboxes[i].setChecked(True)
            except Exception as e:
                print str(e)
    # compare layer list at creation and now to notice difference
    elif self.tmp_layers != self.layers:
        for i in range(0, self.scrollLayout.count()):
            self.scrollLayout.removeItem(self.scrollLayout.itemAt(0))
            try:  # delete old layer items
                for i in range(0, len(self.layers)):
                    self.scrollLayout.addWidget(self.checkboxes[i])
                    self.checkboxes[i].setChecked(True)
            except Exception as e:
                print str(e)
```

Function cBoxChecked() is as follows:

```
    def cBoxChecked(self, cBox):
    """ Add functionality  to ScrollArea checkboxes."""
    if cBox.isChecked():
          if cBox.text() not in api.selected_upload_layers:
               api.selected_upload_layers.append(cBox.text())
    else:
          try:
               api.selected_upload_layers.remove(cBox.text())
          except Exception as e:
               print str(e)
```

Alhtough now i don't get any exceptions, and the list is regenerated. I'm noticing old list underneath the new one, which means that I'm not deleting layout correctly (there are various questions for layout deletion) but I couldn't figure it out completely. To sum it up. What is the most convenient way of destroying and recreating layout and how to figure out parent-child QObject relationships in this concrete example? And one more question that bothers me is that with every new opening of settings tab, there seems to be logic revertion in lambda function that does all the heavy lifting for selecting certain CheckBox. How to fix that?
Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The main problem was removeItem method which didn't worked as planned. Although the whole thing was a mess. What I did now? I created checkboxes list at the class initialization as empty list and with correct conditions I'm checking is it first time the SettingsDock is invoked, or is it invoked after something changed in layer interface list. The code is as folows.If something is not explained properly in comments, feel free to ask why i did it that way. Cheers

```
    self.layers = qgis_api.get_layers()
    reduced_layers = []
    # reduced_layers is list variable which is populated with all layers
    # without redundant ones (same names of multiple files .shp/.shx/.dbf)
    # shapefile file format 
    for layer in self.layers:
        if layer.name() not in reduced_layers:
            reduced_layers.append(layer.name())

    # ScrollArea setup
    # Set up settingsDock.groupBox as a parent of Vertical layout
    # Check if Settings was clicked before api.upload would be handy for
    # that, scroll is QScrollArea and is added as widget with layout as
    # parent, after that I set up Scroll Content as widget with scroll
    # as parent, while scroll Layout is Vertical layout with scrollContent
    # as parent, but then i use scroll.setWidget method to define it as
    # a parent to scrollContent 
    if (api.selected_upload_layers == [] and
        api.project.layerTreeRoot().children() != []):
        self.tmp_layers = qgis_api.get_layers()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.settingsDock.groupBox)
        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        # self.layout.addWidget(self.scroll)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setFixedHeight(111)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scroll)
        self.scrollContent = QWidget(self.scroll)
        self.scrollLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.scrollContent)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.scrollContent)

    # As self.checkboxes are initialized as empty list, here are we
    # generating a list of QCheckBox items with layer names(if there are
    # multiple layers with same name(shapefile format), only one will be
    # added as checkbox
    # After generating checkboxes list we use it to populate widgets,
    # QCheckBoxes in ScrollLayout, and set it in default as Checked
    # This is basically 1st time initialization
    if self.checkboxes == []:
        try:
            for i in range(0, len(self.layers)):
                if self.layers[i].name() not in map(lambda x: x.text(),
                                                    self.checkboxes):
                    self.checkboxes.append(QCheckBox('{}'.format(
                                            self.layers[i].name())))
            for i in range(0, len(self.checkboxes)):
                self.scrollLayout.addWidget(self.checkboxes[i])
                self.checkboxes[i].setChecked(True)
                api.selected_upload_layers = map(lambda x: x.text(),
                                                 self.checkboxes)
        except Exception as e:
            print str(e)

    # if checkboxes are different from layer list (that is generated) in
    # the moment of clicking show settings which basically indicates that
    # interface layer list has been chaged, we must update checkboxes
    # To update checkboxes list it's firstly deleted with ScrollContent
    elif map(lambda x: x.text(), self.checkboxes) != reduced_layers:
        num = self.scrollLayout.count()
        self.scrollLayout.removeWidget(self.scrollContent)
        self.scrollContent.deleteLater()
        self.scrollContent = QWidget(self.scroll)
        self.scrollLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.scrollContent)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.scrollContent)
        try:
            self.checkboxes = []
            for i in range(0, len(self.layers)):
                if self.layers[i].name() not in map(lambda x: x.text(), self.checkboxes):
                    self.checkboxes.append(QCheckBox('{}'.format(
                                            self.layers[i].name())))
            for i in range(0, len(self.checkboxes)):
                self.scrollLayout.addWidget(self.checkboxes[i])
                self.checkboxes[i].setChecked(True)
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)

    for i in range(0, len(self.checkboxes)):
        self.checkboxes[i].stateChanged.connect(lambda checked, i=i:
                                            self.checkBoxChecked())
```

Function checkBoxChecked() is as follows:

```
    def checkBoxChecked(self):
    """Add functionality to ScrollArea checkboxes."""
    #print api.selected_upload_layers
    indices = []
    for i in range(0, len(self.checkboxes)):
        if self.checkboxes[i].isChecked():
            # print cBox.isChecked()
            print self.checkboxes[i].text() + " is selected"
            indices.append(i)
        else:
            print self.checkboxes[i].text() + " is deselected"

    api.selected_upload_layers = [map(lambda x: x.text(), self.checkboxes)[i] for i in indices]
```